# Export default object in redux reducer

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, ecmascript-5

```js
import VersionReducer from "./VersionReducer";

export default combineReducers({
    appVersion: VersionReducer
});
```

In my VersionReducer.js file

When I use the following, everything is fine

```js
export default () => [{
    versionNumber: 22,
    versionName: "2.2"
}];
```

But I want to get object from this. like this

```js
export default {
    versionNumber: 22,
    versionName: "2.2.1"
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (in VersionReducer.js):

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    versionNumber: 22,
    versionName: "2.2.1"
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    return state
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the file a JSON file, and then remove then `export default` part of the file.

That way, when you import the file in your combine reducers file, you get the whole object.

So your VersionReducer file should be renamed to `VersionReducer.json` and it's contents should be:

```
{
    "versionNumber": 22,
    "versionName": "2.2.1"
}
```

That should work.